# On the closed form for $\sum_{m=0}^\infty \prod_{n=1}^m\frac{n}{5n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2009343/4781), we find,

$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty \prod_{n=1}^m\frac{n}{3n-1}=\frac{3}{2}+a_1\ln a_2+a_3\sqrt{3}\,\arctan\big(a_4\sqrt{3}\big)$$

$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty \prod_{n=1}^m\frac{n}{4n-1}=\frac{4}{3}+b_1\ln b_2+b_3\sqrt{4}\,\arctan\big(b_4\sqrt{4}\big)$$

where the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are roots of ***cubics*** and ***quartics***, respectively. Would it follow that $p=5$ would have the same form,

$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty \prod_{n=1}^m\frac{n}{5n-1}=\frac{5}{4}+c_1\ln c_2+c_3\sqrt{5}\,\arctan\big(c_4\sqrt{5}\big)$$

and the $c_i$ are now roots of ***quintics***, or is it just hasty generalization? If indeed true, then what are the $c_i$?

Comment: Do we have cases for 1 and 2?

Comment: For $p=2$ I get an answer of $1+\pi/2$ however I am unsure if I can rearrange it into your form.

Comment: In any case, it would not *follow* in any posible sense fro the two equalities you know that the third one holds. At te very most you canconjecture it does, but nothing follows...

Comment: The sum can be written as $$\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac1{5^m\binom{m-\frac15}{m}}$$

Comment: All Gauss hyp $\, _2F_1\left(1,1;\frac{m}{k};z\right)$ can be written in terms of elementary functions, which naturally leads to all result OP posted, together with generalizations below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think all the ingredient are already given by previous answers, such as [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889117/find-a-closed-form-for-this-infinite-sum-1-frac-1-2-frac1-times22-tim).

Following the same idea, if $p \geq 2$ is an integer and $Z_p = \{ \zeta \in \Bbb{C} : \zeta^p + p - 1 = 0 \}$, then

\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \prod_{n=1}^{m} \frac{n}{pn-1} = 
&= 1 + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{p x^{-1/p}}{(x + p - 1)^2} \, dx \\
&= \frac{p}{p-1} + \frac{1}{p-1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{pu^{p-2}}{u^p + p - 1} \, du \qquad (x = u^p) \\
&= \frac{p}{p-1} + \frac{1}{p-1} \sum_{\zeta \in Z_p} \frac{1}{\zeta} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{du}{u-\zeta} \\
&= \frac{p}{p-1} + \frac{1}{p-1} \sum_{\zeta \in Z_p} \frac{1}{\zeta} \log\left(1 - \frac{1}{\zeta}\right),
\end{align*}

where the standard branch cut $\arg z \in (-\pi, \pi)$ is used to define the complex logarithm $\log z$. Then all you have to do is to simplify the summation for each $p$. It is laborious but not impossible to do, using the fact that

$$ Z_p = \{ (p-1)^{1/p} e^{(2k-1)\pi i/p} : k = 1, \cdots, p \}. $$

Indeed, with $r = (p-1)^{1/p}$ and $\theta_k = (2k-1)\pi/p$ we have

$$\begin{split}
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \prod_{n=1}^{m} \frac{n}{pn-1}
& = \frac{p}{p-1} + \frac{1}{(p-1)r} \sum_{k=1}^{p} \bigg[ \cos \theta_k \log\sqrt{\smash[b]{r^2 - 2r\cos\theta_k + 1}} \\
&\hspace{13em} + \sin \theta_k \arctan \bigg(\frac{\sin\theta_k}{r - \cos\theta_k} \bigg)\bigg]
\end{split} \tag{*} $$

*Comments.*

- Since this will result in roughly $\frac{p}{2}$ logarithmic terms (resp. arctangent terms), I see no reason that they merge into a single logarithm term (resp. single arctangent term) involving only algebraic numbers for any $p$.
- Of course, we expect that the representation $\text{(*)}$ reduces to a single log term and a single arctan term when $p = 2, 3, 4, 6$. This is because both $\{\cos \theta_k\}$ and $\{\sin\theta_k\}$ have rank 1 over $\Bbb{Q}$ for these $p$'s. Indeed, when $p = 6$ we have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \prod_{n=1}^{m} \frac{n}{6n-1}
&= \frac{6}{5}
+ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{10 \cdot 5^{1/6}} \log\bigg( \frac{5^{1/3} - \sqrt{3} \cdot 5^{1/6} + 1}{5^{1/3} + \sqrt{3} \cdot 5^{1/6} + 1} \bigg) \\
&\hspace{5em} + \frac{1}{5^{7/6}} \bigg( \pi - \arctan \bigg( \frac{10-5\cdot 5^{1/3} + 9 \cdot 5^{2/3}}{13\sqrt{5}} \bigg) \bigg) \\
&\approx 1.2441289574532625062\cdots
 \end{align*}

Comment: Very good point, indeed. I suppose that the $\frac 64$ should be $\frac 65$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, You are right, that is $\frac{6}{5}$. My fingers often betray me. :p

Comment: Beautiful for $p=6$!

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII, Thank you for pointing out the typo. I appreciate it.

Comment: I used an equivalent expression. I hope you are ok with it.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that we could assume that these expressions will have the same form since

$$P_3=\prod_{n=1}^m\frac{n}{3n-1}=3^{-m}\frac{ \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \Gamma (m+1)}{\Gamma
   \left(m+\frac{2}{3}\right)}$$
$$P_4=\prod_{n=1}^m\frac{n}{4n-1}=4^{-m}\frac{ \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right) \Gamma (m+1)}{\Gamma
   \left(m+\frac{3}{4}\right)}$$
$$P_5=\prod_{n=1}^m\frac{n}{5n-1}=5^{-m}\frac{ \Gamma \left(\frac{4}{5}\right) \Gamma (m+1)}{\Gamma
   \left(m+\frac{4}{5}\right)}$$
$$P_6=\prod_{n=1}^m\frac{n}{6n-1}=6^{-m}\frac{ \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{6}\right) \Gamma (m+1)}{\Gamma
   \left(m+\frac{5}{6}\right)}$$ where a quite clear patterm appears.

This makes the summations to be

$$S_3=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \prod_{n=1}^m\frac{n}{3n-1}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty P_3=\, _2F_1\left(1,1;\frac{2}{3};\frac{1}{3}\right)$$
$$S_4=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \prod_{n=1}^m\frac{n}{4n-1}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty P_4=\, _2F_1\left(1,1;\frac{3}{4};\frac{1}{4}\right)$$
$$S_5=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \prod_{n=1}^m\frac{n}{5n-1}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty P_5=\, _2F_1\left(1,1;\frac{4}{5};\frac{1}{5}\right)$$
$$S_6=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \prod_{n=1}^m\frac{n}{6n-1}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty P_6=\, _2F_1\left(1,1;\frac{5}{6};\frac{1}{6}\right)$$
where a quite clear pattern appears.

Expanding, we then have (before any simplifications)

$$S_3=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\log \left(1+\frac{1}{2^{2/3}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}\right)}{4
   \sqrt[3]{2}}-\frac{\log \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}\right)}{2
   \sqrt[3]{2}}-\frac{\sqrt{3} \cot ^{-1}\left(\frac{1-2
   \sqrt[3]{2}}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}{2 \sqrt[3]{2}}$$

$$S_4=\frac{4}{3}+\frac{\log
   \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt[4]{3}}\right)}{3 \sqrt{2}
   \sqrt[4]{3}}-\frac{\log
   \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt[4]{3}}\right)}{3 \sqrt{2}
   \sqrt[4]{3}}+\frac{\sqrt{2} \cot ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2} \sqrt[4]{3}
   \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt[4]{3}}\right)\right)}{3
   \sqrt[4]{3}}+\frac{\sqrt{2} \cot ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2} \sqrt[4]{3}
   \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt[4]{3}}\right)\right)}{3 \sqrt[4]{3}}$$

$$S_5=\frac{5}{4}-\frac{\log \left(1+\frac{1}{2^{2/5}}\right)}{4\
   2^{2/5}}-\frac{\left(\sqrt{5}-1\right) \log
   \left(1+\frac{1}{2^{4/5}}-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2\ 2^{2/5}}\right)}{16\
   2^{2/5}}-\frac{\left(-1-\sqrt{5}\right) \log
   \left(1+\frac{1}{2^{4/5}}-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2\ 2^{2/5}}\right)}{16\
   2^{2/5}}+\frac{\sqrt{\frac{5}{8}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}} \cot
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{2^{2/5} \left(1-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4\
   2^{2/5}}\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{5}{8}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}}}\right)}{2\
   2^{2/5}}+\frac{\sqrt{\frac{5}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}} \cot
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{2^{2/5} \left(1-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4\
   2^{2/5}}\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{5}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}}}\right)}{2\ 2^{2/5}}$$

$$S_6=\frac{6}{5}+\frac{\sqrt{3} \log
   \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{5}}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt[6]{5}}\right)}{10
   \sqrt[6]{5}}-\frac{\sqrt{3} \log
   \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{5}}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt[6]{5}}\right)}{10
   \sqrt[6]{5}}+\frac{2 \cot ^{-1}\left(\sqrt[6]{5}\right)}{5
   \sqrt[6]{5}}+\frac{\cot ^{-1}\left(2 \sqrt[6]{5} \left(1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2
   \sqrt[6]{5}}\right)\right)}{5 \sqrt[6]{5}}+\frac{\cot ^{-1}\left(2
   \sqrt[6]{5} \left(1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt[6]{5}}\right)\right)}{5
   \sqrt[6]{5}}$$
Now, for sure, you can recombine the logarithms and the arccotangents terms to arrive to the kind of expressions you posted for $S_3$ and $S_4$ because the coefficients are the same (same for $S_6$).

For $S_5$ and $S_6$, if feasible for the logarithms, it seems that it could be much more tedious with the arccotangents terms.

In my opinion, the simplest "closed" forms should be the hypergeometric functions.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll try to simplify the case $p=5$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII. Have fun !!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\end{align}
Given the *Pochhammer symbol* $\displaystyle (a)_m =\frac{\Gamma(a+m)}{\Gamma(a)}$, and where $\Gamma(a)$ is the *gamma function*. Then,

\begin{align}
&\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\prod_{n = 1}^{m}{n \over 5n - 1} =
\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 5^{m}}\prod_{n = 1}^{m}{n \over n - 1/5} =  \color{blue}{1.32062\dots} 
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 5^{m}}\,{m! \over \pars{4/5}_{m}}
\qquad\qquad\qquad
\\[5mm] = &\
1+\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}{m \over 5^{m}}\,{\Gamma\pars{m}\Gamma\pars{4/5} \over \Gamma\pars{4/5 + m}} =
1+\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}{m \over 5^{m}}
\int_{0}^{1}t^{m - 1}\pars{1 - t}^{-1/5}\,\dd t
\\[5mm]= &\
1+\int_{0}^{1}\
\pars{\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}{m \over 5^{m}}\ t^{m - 1}}
 \pars{1 - t}^{-1/5}\,\dd t
\\[5mm]= &\
1+\int_{0}^{1}\
\pars{5 \over \pars{5 - t}^{2}}
 \pars{1 - t}^{-1/5}\,\dd t =  \color{blue}{1.32062\dots} 
\end{align}

> Indeed, the final integration is rather cumbersome and it doesn't look close to your guess: It has $\ds{\underline{\mbox{four}}\ \ln}$ with different arguments and $\ds{\underline{\mbox{two}}\ \,\mrm{arccot}}$ with different arguments too.

Comment: In the case $p=4$, WolframAlpha evaluates it with ***two*** logs and ***two*** arccots but can be simplified to just one log and one arccot. Perhaps a similar simplification can be done with $p=5$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Maybe there's a simplification. But it's cumbersome. You can try it. Thanks for your remark.